# How do I get Cloud9 out of read-only mode when connecting remotely?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud9-ide

I have Cloud9 IDE installed on Ubuntu 12.04 running on NodeJS 0.8.11.  It works just fine if I run it locally (ie localhost:3131).

However, if I try to open it from a remote machine on my own network, it will only open in read-only mode.  I can open all the files, move the cursor around, but cannot type or create new files.

I know this is some sort of permission problem, but I can't figure out how to fix it.  I've tried starting cloud9 as root, my own user account, and apache's user account (www-data). No luck with any of them.

I have an Apache reverse proxy set up to access the cloud9 instance. The VirtualHost entry looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName c9.mk802 
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3131/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3131/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure if this is an Apache problem, a cloud9 problem, or an Ubuntu problem. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Open cloud9/configs/default.js and change all instances of "localhost" to "0.0.0.0".  This will allow Apache to connect with whatever domain name is specified in the reverse proxy.

This probably is not very secure, so make sure the cloud9 server is not exposed outside of your network.

Answer (score 1):

The default file logic in `configs/default.js` is as follows:

```
var host = argv.l || process.env.IP || "localhost";
```

As a result, you can accomplish the same answer above without having to modify the default config by using the `-l` switch, like so:

```
cloud9 $> node server.js -l 0.0.0.0
```

This causes cloud9 to start, but listening on all traffic.